# Convert jpg Image to Tiff in nodejs without using imagemagick

Tags: node.js, linux, image, tiff

I want to convert the jpg Image to tiff format using nodejs without imagemagick and graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat packages install.

Due to Third party library for security purposes. Any other way possible for convert jpg to tiff. Kindly share your suggestion.

Convert and mogrify commands are used for convert jpg to tiff format. Without using imagemagick Third party library any other possible in nodejs or Linux tools.

Based upon Linux command we execute in nodejs Child process.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use **NetPBM**. So, firstly you'll need `jpegtopnm` then `pnmtotiff`, which will mean something like:

```
jpegtopnm YOURIMAGE.JPG | pnmtotiff > result.tif
```

As you want to use `node.js`, I am assuming you will need to *"shell out"* to **NetPBM** with some type of `system()` call.